# Apache NiFi - Listen UDP/TCP ranges

Tags: range, apache-nifi, processors

I'm trying to configure the ListenUDP or ListenTCP processors to get input from multiple, but very specific IP's.  I'm trying to find out if IP ranges can be used instead of a single IP, this way all my palo altos will go to one processor, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

ListenTCP & ListenUDP do not filter incoming traffic.

You can choose which network interface is used to listen for incoming traffic by setting `Local Network Interface` - so you can apply normal filtering techniques such as iptables or a firewall to filter what traffic is allowed to reach that network interface.

In theory, recieved messages do write an attribute `tcp.sender` or `udp.sender` to each FlowFile. So you could technically filter AFTER the ListenTCP by comparing the value of this Attribute and dropping messages that are not valid...but this is a lot less efficient than filtering network traffic outside of NiFi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sdairs. I was wondering since the Processors has a field for it called "Sending Host" and "Sending Host Port"